# DomainAccessGuard.Sessions is Always null

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Hi I am having trouble Integrating the ability to kick users as the sessionCollection is always null.

```
public void KickStaleUsers()
    {
        foreach (DomainAccessGuard.Session ses in DomainAccessGuard.Sessions) //<--- This is null
        {
            if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(ses.LastRequest).Minutes >= 60)
            {
                DomainAccessGuard.Kick(ses.SessionID);
                Log.Info("Brugeren (" + ses.UserName + ") er logget ud grundet 60 min. inaktivitet!", this);
            }
        }
    }
```

I am running this from an agent

Does anybody know why it is null?

Comment: If it's DomainAccessGuard.Sessions that's null, not the individual session you're testing, then you'l need to post up the code where you create the object. Is it DomainAccessGuard that's null, or is its sessions collection empty (if its null then you'll need to look in the class code) or is it actually a Session from within the collection that's null?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: See comment to question.
More code/clarification required.

If `DomainAccessGuard` is null then post the code from where you create the object.

If `DomainAccessGuard.Sessions` is empty then post the code where the sessions collection is filled.

If `DomainAccessGuard.Sessions` (the collection) is `null` then you'll need to post the code where the collection is instantiated - though I'd find that a little strange.

If the individual `DomainAccessGuard.Session` from within the collection that you're trying to access the `UserName` of is null then the following might apply:

It looks to me like you're trying to read the user name from a session you've just kicked. Wouldn't that make your session null?

This might work:

```
Log.Info("Brugeren (" + ses.UserName + ") er logget ud grundet 60 min. inaktivitet!", this);
DomainAccessGuard.Kick(ses.SessionID);
```

That's just a guess, I know nothing about DomainAccessGuard.

Comment: DomainAccessGuard can be instantiated but, all methods are static so it makse no sense, to do it or am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `DomainAccessGuard.GetAccess()` to initialize the Sessions collection

```
if(DomainAccessGuard.GetAccess())
{
    foreach (DomainAccessGuard.Session ses in DomainAccessGuard.Sessions) //<--- This is null
    {
        if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(ses.LastRequest).Minutes >= 60)
        {
            DomainAccessGuard.Kick(ses.SessionID);
            Log.Info("Brugeren (" + ses.UserName + ") er logget ud grundet 60 min. inaktivitet!", this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It isn't working, I am still getting a nullReference:

Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Web.Authentication.DomainAccessGuard.GetAccess(User domainUser)
   at FTZ.CMS.Automatics.UserAgent.KickStaleUsers() in C:\Website\Automatics\UserAgent.cs:line 15

Comment: hmm. When I tried it inside a test MVC method I got the above error but adding the GetAccess() method made it work. Using reflector I found that that is the method that instantiates the Sessions collection. I just tried the same in a scheduled task and you're right the GetAccess() method throws the above error however if I remove it it runs fine. Are you doing anything else in your agent like switching site context or anything else?

Comment: Not sure if it makes a difference but I'm on the latest 6.4.1 release (110324)

Comment: I'm on 6.4.0, checking the changelog for 6.4.1

Comment: Nothing in the changelog and i'm still getting errors


Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: FTZ.CMS
   at FTZ.CMS.Automatics.UserAgent.KickStaleUsers() in C:\Website\Automatics\UserAgent.cs:line 16

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sitecore documentation which provides an [example of how to reduce session timeout](http://sdn.sitecore.net/faq/security/sessionexpiration.aspx).

It runs as an agent, and also has an Assert.IsNotNull check on session.

Hope this helps